# Compute $Tor$ and $Ext$ over ring of matrices

Tags: homological-algebra

Let  $R$   be   the   ring   $M_n(k)$ of matrices of order  $n$   over   the   field  $k$. Compute  $Tor_n^R(M,N)$   and $Ext_R^n(P, Q)$   for  any $n \geq 0$ and   every  $M, N,P,Q$ - $R$ modules(left   or  right  such  that  $Tor$  and  $Ext$ have  sense.  My  idea is    to   find  a   projective  resolution  in  every case but  I  can't...

Comment: Do you know that the category of modules over $M_n(k)$ is equivalent to the category of $k$ vector spaces?

Comment: The matrix ring $M_n(k)$ is semisimple (simple even).

Comment: @Hanno  I  don't  know   that.  Why   is   useful?

Comment: @Hanno Is this true?I do not know this,where can I find it?I think this is amazing '

Comment: @Sky That   is   useful   for   the   problem?

Answer (score 3):

The ring $R=M_n(k)$ is semisimple (Wedderburn’s theorem or direct proof), so every module in projective and injective.

More generally, if $S$ is a ring, then the functor $F=\operatorname{Hom}(P_S,-)$ is a category equivalence between $\text{Mod-}S$ and $\text{Mod-}R$, where $R=M_n(S)$ and $P=S^n$. The inverse equivalence is $G=-\otimes_RP$ (seeing $P$ as a left module over $R$, its endomorphism ring as right $S$-module).

It's easy to prove, using exactness of $F$ and $G$, that for every pair of modules $M,N\in\text{Mod-}R$,
$$
\operatorname{Ext}_R^n(M,N)\cong\operatorname{Ext}_S^n(GM,GN)
$$
(as abelian groups). Similarly for Tor.

Comment: Yes,for any ring $R$,$R\cong End(R)^{op}$ .